# Is DAO responsible for inserting records into 'join' table

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, dao

For example, if I have two tables: `Customer` and `Product` and I need to map customers to products (many-to-many). So I need a third (join) table, which will contain `CustomerId` and `ProductId`.  Is `DAO`  responsible for inserting records into the third (join) table?

P.S. For now I have `CustomerDAO` and `ProductDAO`. Mapping customers to products handled by a service-layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your DAO can implement methods like

- updateProduct(CustomerId)
- updateCustomer(ProductId)
- findCustomerByProduct(productId)
- findProductsByCustomer(customerId)

Comment: I.e. both DAOs (CustomerDAO and ProductDAO) can now about third table?

Comment: yes, you will interact with both the instances in this join-DAO

Comment: Thanks. But what about `assignCustomerToProduct(int customerId, String productId)` method? This method will insert record into third table. Can I have such method inside `CustomerDAO`?

Comment: Those r not hard rules , just to give an idea . Yes the method name u mentioned is more meaningful

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course, it is its responsibility. If not `DAO`, then who will do it instead of it?

Comment: For now it's implemented in service layer (see updated question).

Comment: As for me, I don't think, that it is the good idea to implement such relationships inside third service layer class.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But where I must implement (in DAO or service-layer?) methods, where I need to found object loose coupled to given object. For example I have `Employee` and  `Manager` entities (with corresponding tables and DAOs). And I need to find Manager of given Employee. But I need to go through a long way to find manager of a given employee (Employee-Product-Provider-Organization-Manager (not real structure, just for example)). Is DAO responsible to have method like this (EmployeeDAO#getManager(int employeeId))? Or it's better to put this method into service layer?